# How to get image data from ShaderMaterial?

Tags: three.js

I have been looking at the ShaderMaterial and noticed there's no map property like in MeshBasicMaterial. I was wondering. How I can gain access to the RGB values of the ShaderMaterial? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want so send a texture to your shader?

Comment: No I wanted to gain access the pixel data of the loaded ShaderMaterial.

Comment: I found a way/work around. Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question.